# How to remove empty string in hash

Tags: ruby, hash

```
{"name"=>"XYZ","address"=>{"street"=>{"street_address"=>"","city"=>"City name"}},"form"=>{"id"=>11,"f_name"=>""},"test"=""}
```

I'd like to get:

```
{"name"=>"XYZ","address"=>{"street"=>{"city"=>"City name"}},"form"=>{"id"=>11}}
```

How do I remove the empty strings?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" including the links at the bottom, and "[mcve]". We'd like to see evidence of your effort, either showing us where you looked as you tried to find information how to solve this, along with an explanation why those pages didn't help, or code and supporting input and expected output data showing what you've tried. Without that it looks like you haven't tried and want us to solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 4):

```
hash = {"name"=>"XYZ",
        "address"=>{"street"=>{"street_address"=>"","city"=>"City name"}},
        "form"=>{"id"=>11,"f_name"=>""},
        "test"=>""}

def remove_blanks hash
  hash.map do |k, v|
    v == '' ? nil : [k, v.is_a?(Hash) ? remove_blanks(v) : v]
  end.compact.to_h
end

remove_blanks hash

#⇒ {
#  "address" => {
#    "street" => {
#      "city" => "City name"
#    }
#  },
#     "form" => {
#    "id" => 11
#  },
#     "name" => "XYZ"
# }
```

Comment: @AndreyDeineko thanks; I have just written the small [mixin for deep hash iteration](https://github.com/am-kantox/iteraptor), that’s probably why :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried with `Proc`

```
 > hash = {"name"=>"XYZ","address"=>{"street"=>{"street_address"=>"","city"=>"City name"}},"form"=>{"id"=>11,"f_name"=>""},"test"=>""}
 > remove_blank = Proc.new { |k, v| v.delete_if(&remove_blank) if v.is_a?(Hash); v == "" }
 > hash.delete_if &remove_blank
 #Output:

# {
#   "name"=>"XYZ", 
#   "address"=>
#     {
#       "street"=>
#         {
#           "city"=>"City name"
#         }
#     }, 
#   "form"=>
#     {
#       "id"=>11
#     }
# }
```

Comment: Awesome, save for that there is no `blank?` method in ruby. Please correct it to make it work outside of rails and I will definitely upvote. _Sidenote_: I did not check, but I guess it will also remove empty hashes, what was not intentionally specified in the OP.

Comment: @mudasobwa : I have replace `blank?` method and updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'

def clean_hash(hash)
  hash.each do |key, value|
    if value.is_a?(Hash)
      clean_hash(value)
    else
      hash.delete(key) if value.blank?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: There is no such method `blank?` in the pure Ruby, only in the Rails.

Comment: @ArtemBiserov then please either correct the answer, or remove it. There is no tag `rails` specified in OP.